# Update Error on VBA .Execute on ADODB Recordset

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, adodb

I am trying to update a SQL DB table through the input from my textbox. The issue I am having can be seen with the generic VBA Sub seen below:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim strSql As String
Dim strADOCon As String

strADOConTechSub = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=______;Initial Catalog=______;User ID = _______; Password = ______;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

conn.Open strADOCon

strSql = "SELECT this " & _ 
         "FROM there  " & _
         "WHERE that <> ''"

Set rst = conn.Execute(strSql)

rst!this.Value = Me.Textbox1

conn.Close
```

I am receiving the error message;

> Run-Time error '3251':
>
> Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation
>   of the provider, or of the selected locktype.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [SQLOLEDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) seems to be deprecated, see MSOLEDBSQL. Why do you have parenthesis around your request?

Comment: As you don't seem to care about the current values there is no reason to SELECT, just execute an UPDATE instead.

Comment: I do not have Parenthesis in my actual select query. I will edit this now. However, I have looked into what you have mentioned and this is relevant but not the issue. I will look into changing over to MSOLEDBSQL in the future.

Comment: I generally recommend just using the ODBC SQL server driver, though. Works fine, and then you don't have a different type of connection for your ADO queries and linked tables, which makes managing dependencies and troubleshooting easier.

Comment: [Updating, Adding And Deleting Records In a Recordset](http://www.accessallinone.com/updating-adding-and-deleting-records-in-a-recordset/) has excellent sample code.